# Python to Java code: String.encode() in java

Tags: java, python, string, encode

I'm trying to emulate a keyboard using a Raspberry Pi, and found some code online that achieves that. On a python base it functions, but now I want to convert it to Java (my main language) to play around with it more.

This is the important part of the python code:

```py
def write_report(report):
    print(report.encode())
    # with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
        # fd.write(report.encode())

# Press a
write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)
```

So the output is the following:
`b'\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

How do I achieve it that the same output is written to the file in java?

Comment: Could you be more descriptive? What exactly are you trying to emulate? Do you want your program to act like you pressed a key on the keyboard?

Comment: @martijnp The Raspi Zero has an OTG port, so it can function as a USB-HID device. It functions that you initialize the device (that happens automatically while boot) and then write the reports to a specific file (here `/dev/hidg0`). So at the computer it is connected to it works like a physical keyboard, so the key is typed.
However, for the question it is irrelevant, it's only important that the exact same thing is written to the file.

Comment: You want to convert a byte array to a hex string?

Comment: @MartinWickman I want to write the exact same thing to the file in java like in python.

Comment: Any ideas? @MartinWickman ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to write the same bytes to the file. Here is the code:

```java
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] {0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0};
    FileOutputStream fWriter;
    try {
        fWriter = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\testJava.txt"));
        fWriter.write(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks!